# Better method to swap the values of two 2-D arrays

Tags: list-manipulation

I have two 2-D matrices $A$ and $B$(owns *same* dimentions) which have the style written as below:

$
\begin{bmatrix}
a_{11} & a_{12} & \cdots  & a_{1k} &\cdots &\cdots & a_{1,2k+1}\\
a_{21} & a_{22} & \cdots  & a_{2k} &\cdots &\cdots & a_{2,2k+1}\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots  & \vdots &\vdots &\cdots & \vdots \\
a_{k1} & a_{k2} & \cdots  & a_{kk} &\cdots &\cdots & a_{k,2k+1}\\
a_{k+1,1} & a_{k+1,2} & \cdots  & a_{k+1,k+1} & a_{k+1,k+1} &\cdots a_{k+1,2k} & a_{k+1,,2k+1}\\
a_{k+2,1} & a_{k+2,2} & \cdots  & a_{k+2,k} &\cdots &\cdots & a_{k+2,,2k+1}\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots  & \vdots &\vdots & \vdots \\
a_{2k+1,1} & a_{2k+1,2} & \cdots  & a_{2k+1,k} &\cdots &\cdots & a_{2k+1,2k+1}\\
\end{bmatrix}
_{2k+1\times 2k+1}
$

Now I want to swap the value of some positions betwen them

> [image]

**My awkward solution**

**Edit** Thanks for @Kuba

```
swap[a_, b_] :=
 Module[{k, A = a, B = b},
  k = Quotient[Length@A, 2];

  {A[[1 ;; k, 1 ;; k]], B[[1 ;; k, 1 ;; k]]} =
   {B[[1 ;; k, 1 ;; k]], A[[1 ;; k, 1 ;; k]]};

  {A[[k + 2 ;; 2 k + 1, 1 ;; k]], B[[k + 2 ;; 2 k + 1, 1 ;; k]]} =
   {B[[k + 2 ;; 2 k + 1, 1 ;; k]], A[[k + 2 ;; 2 k + 1, 1 ;; k]]};

  {A[[k + 1, k + 1 ;; 2 k]], B[[k + 1, k + 1 ;; 2 k]]} =
   {B[[k + 1, k + 1 ;; 2 k]], A[[k + 1, k + 1 ;; 2 k]]};
  {A, B}
]
```

**Test**

```
mat1 = Partition[Range[1, 25], 5];
mat2 = Partition[Range[26, 50], 5];
MatrixForm /@ {mat1, mat2}
MatrixForm /@ swap[mat1, mat2]
```

> [image]

In addition, I have a trial to refactor the code

```
  {A[[1 ;; k, 1 ;; k]], B[[1 ;; k, 1 ;; k]]} =
   {B[[1 ;; k, 1 ;; k]], A[[1 ;; k, 1 ;; k]]};

  {A[[k + 2 ;; 2 k + 1, 1 ;; k]], B[[k + 2 ;; 2 k + 1, 1 ;; k]]} =
   {B[[k + 2 ;; 2 k + 1, 1 ;; k]], A[[k + 2 ;; 2 k + 1, 1 ;; k]]};
```

to the below style

```
{A[[{1 ;; k, k + 2 ;; 2 k + 1}, 1 ;; k]], B[[{1 ;; k, k + 2 ;; 2 k + 1}, 1 ;; k]]} =
 {B[[{1 ;; k, k + 2 ;; 2 k + 1}, 1 ;; k]], A[[{1 ;; k, k + 2 ;; 2 k + 1}, 1 ;; k]]}
```

However, I failed in this trial and it seems that `Span(;;)` doesn't own this usage.

**Question**

- Is there other better methods(solutions) to implement this swap operation?

Comment: There are two $a_{k+1,k+1}$ in the matrix?

Comment: @xzczd, a mistake:D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ClearAll[swapF]
swapF = Module[{m1 = #, m2 = #2, k = Floor[Length[#]/2]},
    Module[{copy = #, rows = Join @@ {Range[k], Range[k + 2, 2 k + 1]}},
       CompoundExpression[copy[[rows, ;; k]] = #2[[rows, ;; k]], 
           copy[[k + 1, k + 1 ;;2k]] = #2[[k + 1, k + 1 ;;2k]]]; copy] & @@@ 
      {{m1, m2}, {m2, m1}}] &;
```

Example:

```
mat1 = Partition[Range[1, 25], 5];
mat2 = Partition[Range[26, 50], 5];
Column@(Row /@ {MatrixForm /@ {mat1, mat2}, MatrixForm /@ swapF[mat1, mat2]})
```

> [image]